# Атрибуты при использовании HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, xml, htmlspecialchars, html, синтаксический-анализ

Я использую HTML Agility Pack для парсинга сайтов на CSharp. Эта библиотека выполняет entity подстановку на весь документ при считывании, даже на содержимое атрибутов. Поэтому, если в атрибуте содержится url, то он станет кривым. Как мне получить исходное значение атрибута без искажения?

З.Ы. Сайт, который я разбираю, неправильный с точки зрения XML, поэтому стандартные методы не работают.

З.Ы.Ы. Я пробывал вызывать DeEntitize на то, что вытаскивается с атрибута, url все равно получается кривым и отличным от исходного. Кажется, что символ который вызывает проблему - это экранирование('\'), но я не могу понять откуда он появляется и сколько их реально стоит подряд.

Comment: Пример кривой разметки показали бы :]

Comment: Если реально кривая разметка, тогда может попробовать свой парсер без агилити. Например, string.IndexOf("") вместе с каким-нибудь якорем типа " url='"

Answer (score 1):

Лично я в свое время просто сделал метод который фиксит проблему костылем в виде .Replace("проблемный набор символов", "правильный символ")
и в итоге получал конечную правильную линку :)

Костыль? Да. Но рабочий и не нужно отказыватся от HtmlAgrilityPack:)